# rviz and openGL

Tags: ros, rviz, 3d-object-recognition, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run rviz but I face this error:

```
[ INFO] [1433549504.115313245]: rviz version 1.11.7
[ INFO] [1433549504.115355680]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[ INFO] [1433549504.568675398]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1433549504.568842811]: OpenGl version: 1.4 (GLSL 0).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Your graphics driver does not support OpenGL 2.1. Please enable software rendering before running RViz (e.g. type 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1').
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I run this: export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 but I still have the same problem.

I installed ork(http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install) on ROS some days ago and it asked me to install MESA. I installed this version of MESA.10.5.4 from this link: http://www.mesa3d.org/

I want to know if the problem is my graphic driver? Is anyone know how I can resolve it?

This is my openGL info:

```
OPENGL info:
Renderer: GeForce GTX/745
Version: 1.4 (2.1.2 NVIDIA 331.113
```

the graphic driver:

```
 description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 745]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
```

---

Edit:

To install ORK, I run **catkin_make**, and it failed in the middle and said it couldn't find mesa libraries. That's why I installed mesa. It needed this library: **libosmesa**

http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install

For mesa, I run this:

./configure  --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --enable-osmesa  --with-osmesa-bits=32

and then **make** it.

I use UBUNTU 14.04 LTS(Trusty)
ROS indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210688/rviz-and-opengl/) by [Zozo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22680/zozo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-06**:
You say you "installed this version of MESA 10.5.4 from this link". What did you do exactly? I doubt orc requires the newest Mesa libs, installing them using your platform's package manager would probably have been enough. If you `make && sudo make install`, then some things are probably broken now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-06**:
Also: which OS, version of OS, which ROS release, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> For mesa, I run this:

> ```
> ./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --enable-osmesa --with-osmesa-bits=32
> ```

> and then make it.

This is probably what is causing your issues: if you also did a `sudo make install`, that has most likely overwritten some files and / or symlinks involved in the 3D acceleration pipeline of your system.

> I use UBUNTU 14.04 LTS [..]

It is generally recommended to use the OS package manager to install software on Ubuntu (and any other Linux distro that has a pkg manager, really). For `libosmesa`, perhaps the following would've been enough:

```
sudo apt-get install libosmesa6-dev
```

You could try and see whether installing those packages restores your system to a working state (remember to rebuild ORK). If not, you might also need to reinstall your graphics card driver.

A properly installed (and working) OpenGL system should show you a `Version 3.x` or `Version 4.x` in your `OpenGL Info` along with some other vendor specific information.

> To install ORK, I run catkin_make, and it failed in the middle and said it couldn't find mesa libraries. [..]

A `rosdep check --from-paths /paths/to/your/ork_ws -i` should've tried to install `libosmesa6-dev`, as it is listed as a `build_depend` in `ork_rendered`'s [package manifest](https://github.com/wg-perception/ork_renderer/blob/b8660ead9fb94734397ce71174be0f6303fe9909/package.xml#L17). I don't see `rosdep` mentioned in the installation document you linked, so perhaps it's an idea to run it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0